# Making hover and active selectors the same

Tags: html, css

I have three images acting as tabs. Each image has a semi-transparent overlay of orange. When you hover over it, the orange opacity will be darker. When you click on the image, the active state should look the same as the hover state.

So I did this:

```
.overlay:hover:after, .job-seekers-nav li.active {
opacity: .8!important;
transition: 1s ease;
}
```

But when I ran my code, I am able to do the hover effect but when I click on a certain image, it would load the right content, and once I hover off the image, the image will revert back to the original semi-orange color and not the darker hovered orange.

html

```
<div class="row main-container job-seekers-nav">
        <!--job seekers tab-->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#light-industrial">
                        <div class="overlay border-bottom-yellow"> 
                            <img src="img/light-industrial.jpg" class="img-responsive center-images">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#general-warehousing">
                        <div class="overlay border-bottom-yellow"> 
                            <img src="img/general-warehousing.jpg" class="img-responsive center-images">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#administrative-work">
                        <div class="overlay border-bottom-yellow"> 
                            <img src="img/administrative-work.jpg" class="img-responsive center-images"/>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--end of job seekers tab-->
    </div>
```

css

```
.job-seekers-nav ul {
padding: 0;
}
.job-seekers-nav li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    }

.overlay {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.overlay:after {
    content:'';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #f4511e;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.overlay:hover:after, .job-seekers-nav li.active {
    opacity: .8!important;
    transition: 1s ease;
}

.border-bottom-yellow {
    border-bottom: 30px solid #fce565;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a :visited option that registers links that have been loaded?

Comment: @theGleep No I don't have one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.overlay:hover:after, 
.job-seekers-nav li.active .overlay:after
{
    opacity: .8!important;
    transition: 1s ease;
}
```

Comment: Yes this was what I was looking for! Thank you so much. I didn't even think about the .overlay:after -_-.